# Qt - how to detect whether the application is running on GNOME or KDE?

Tags: linux, qt, desktop, gnome, kde-plasma

I was wondering how I could do something like this ([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=2541e8a6a069d860d0e75b441b800bc5&p=4032584&postcount=10)) using Qt. I looked through the documentation but couldn't find any method to check if an external process is running.

```
if [ "$(pidof ksmserver)" ]; then
   echo "KDE running."
   # KDE-specific stuff here
elif [ "$(pidof gnome-session)" ]; then
   echo "GNOME running."
   # GNOME-specific stuff here
elif [ "$(pidof xfce-mcs-manage)" ]; then
   echo "Xfce running."
   # Xfce-specific stuff here
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QProcess to run `pidof foo`, then check its stdout? If this is not what you want, search `/proc/`.

Answer (score 8):

Normally you shouldn't do this. Generally, if your application behaves differently depending on desktop environment, that will be a nasty surprise for any user that switches between them.

## The alternative

Use DE-agnostic commands like [`xdg-open`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open). Advantages:

- You don't have to write the logic yourself (xdg-utils already has done this)
- More user-friendly. It follows the user's actual preferences; many users use one DE but prefer some applications from a different DE.
- Supports other DEs like XFCE, LXDE, Unity, etc..

For example, instead of opening a URL in Firefox or Konqueror according to the currently-running DE, pass the URL to `xdg-open` to open it in the user's preferred application. (The user might be a Chromium user.) Don't hard-code `nautilus` or `dolphin` for GNOME and KDE; instead open the path using `xdg-open`.

Similarly, for other forms of interaction with the DE, try to use [Freedesktop specifications](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications), rather than trying to guess what DE is running. Standards exist for [moving files to the trash](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec), adding system tray applets, and adding files to the Recent Files list, among others.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way to do what pidof does is to look at entries in /proc.  There's another thread on this here: [Find PID of a Process by Name without Using popen() or system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374997/find-pid-of-a-process-by-name-without-using-popen-or-system)