# Check if process is running (using process name)

Tags: go

Is there anyway in Go to check if a proces is running by searching by process name?  I see ways to do it with PID, however I don't have the PID to search by.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-10.html,
[Find PID of a Process by Name without Using popen() or system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374997/find-pid-of-a-process-by-name-without-using-popen-or-system)

No direct way available. You can use `os/exec` with pidof or pgrep to do this. Or read into procfs.

Comment: Using: ps aux | awk '/process/ && !/awk/ {print $2} should work great for me.